# Different actvities depending on multiple checkboxes /Android

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a button that links to another activity, when I click on it it goes to the layout.xml I want it to

This is the java file for the main/first screen

```
Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, App2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });

}
```

I now have 3 checkboxes on the first screen/activity and the button is labeled "next" 
I want to make so that if you check a different boxes, the button "next" will link to a different activity 
example: checkboxes labeled 1, 2 and 3, when you check 1 and 2 and clic on next yoy go to a activity =3 , if you check 2 and 3 you go to the 5

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like that:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        if (checkBoxA.isChecked())
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AppActivityA.class);
            startActivity(intent);  
        } 
        else if (checkBoxB.isChecked())
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AppActivityB.class);
            startActivity(intent);  
        }
        else if (checkBoxC.isChecked())
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AppActivityC.class);
            startActivity(intent);  
        }
    }
});
```

Have no IDE right now so I didn't check it, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

first do this...when you click yourbutton
get the checkboxes which you checked...

```
CheckBox cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.yourview);
boolean checked=cd.isChecked();// status of checkbox

if(checked){
   // perform action 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have all possibilities covered

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        int add1 = cb1.isChecked() ? 1:0;
        int add2 = cb2.isChecked() ? 2:0;
        int add3 = cb3.isChecked() ? 3:0;
        switch(add1+add2+add3) {
        case 0: Intent intent = new Intent(context, App0Activity.class); break;
        case 1: Intent intent = new Intent(context, App1Activity.class); break;
        case 2: Intent intent = new Intent(context, App2Activity.class); break;
        case 3: Intent intent = new Intent(context, App3Activity.class); break;
        case 4: Intent intent = new Intent(context, App4Activity.class); break;
        case 5: Intent intent = new Intent(context, App5Activity.class); break;
        case 6: Intent intent = new Intent(context, App6Activity.class); break;
        }
        startActivity(intent);   

    }
```